# how to debug MsgValueRequired in yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a yesod application that shows `MsgValueRequired` (english rendering: "Invalid Arguments: Value is required") sometimes, and I want to find out why.

Yesod uses this message, e.g., for hidden input fields: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/1b5477bc786649cd909b87d5e5230c2ba4015395/yesod-form/Yesod/Form/Fields.hs#L250 , and for `mreq` https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/e7c6d06d3dca7710b6bad2caa074162170b82a78/yesod-form/Yesod/Form/Functions.hs#L117

But it gives no information on which field is responsible (and my page has lots).

Is there a way to attach some more information (automatically)?